# How to dedicate a single GPU to single notebook tensorflow 2.2 version in ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, multi-gpu

I have 4 GPU's in my system and I am trying to dedicate each GPU to each notebook(4 GPU's to 4 notebooks in my case). I found that using `with tf.device('/device:GPU:2')` work in tensorflow 1 but it is not working in Tensorflow 2.2 version. Also I tried using `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="2"` to access `'/device:GPU:2'` in one notebook but unable to achieve it. Could you please help how can I do it in Tensorflow 2.2 version.

Comment: Try to add `os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"` before `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="2"`

Comment: Hi Ghanem, Thanks for your suggestion. Your suggestion  actually worked Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering in the answer section for the benefit of the community. Thanks to [Ghanem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3261292/ghanem) for the answer.

The issue was fixed doing as below -

> Try to add os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID" before os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="2"